# apt-get cannot find any packages

Tags: ubuntu, netbook, packages, apt-get

I get this result on my newly installed ubuntu 9.04 netbook remix. I haven't tampered with any apt files at all. It doesnt work for any other packages.

```
ira@ira-windu100:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install git.core
[sudo] password for ira: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package git.core
ira@ira-windu100:/etc/apt$
```

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 2):

You should first search git packages (git.core package doesn't exists)

```
apt-cache search git --names-only
```

When you search an un-installed package, you can run :

```
sudo apt-file search git-core
```

To install it, simply run :

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

In the present case, you just have to run :

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Last but not least, you should run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

like Oliver Salzburg said.

Comment: this: "apt-cache search git --names-only" doesnt give me any output. when I try to install apt-file I get "ira@ira-windu100:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package apt-file
ira@ira-windu100:/etc/apt$ 
"

Comment: Did you ran `sudo apt-get update` ?

Answer (score 0):

9.04 reached end of life in October of 2010; you need to install a supported release.

Answer (score 0):

As Psusi said, Ubuntu 9.04 is no longer supported. If you really need to use it, you can change your /etc/apt/sources.list to something like:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then just `apt-get update && apt-get install git-core`. You'll probably want to upgrade to a supported release. Follow the directions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Jaunty